# slow vnc connection to a vmware workstation virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, vmware-workstation, vnc

I've got 2 computers :
-host in which is installed workstation 12 and a VM called "guest" (linux)
- a laptop, in the same room as the host

I get a fine wired connection between the 2 computers (host+a laptop), but, using wifi + VNC, the graphical user interface of the guest OS has a lag, the moves of the mouse cursor are slow, the windows take a long time to be moved too

here is some technical stuff:
- host : a barebone with 16Gb of memory, the OS is linux mint 17.3
- guest : fedora x64
- laptop : lenovo + core i3, OS : windows 10 x64. VNC client : realVNC
- the wifi connection between host & laptop is in theory of 430 Mb, but the measures give 65 Mb(it passes through the box which slows the connection)

I have 2 questions:
-is it possible to have a decent control over the guest through the laptop via wifi?
-if so, what is the minimum required speed?
-if the connection is too slow, what are the particular points which slow the connection?(the VNC server in host?the speed of the wifi connection?the host hard disk accesses?..)

thanks.
olivier

Answer (score 2):

I've run VNC sessions over much less bandwidth (<1Mb/s) across links which *should* have much greater latency than your setup and found it quite usable. I don't think the network is your problem.

"Slow" is not a very good description. That might mean:

- lag - there is a delay between events being triggered and appearing on screen. This would be particularly noticeable when opening windows. Primarily a latency issue.
- lumpy - sometimes the redraws seem to keep up, sometimes they stall. Scheduling issue but may indicate high packet loss which which quickly evolve into...
- progressive - responses start immediately, but take time to render - bandwidth issue.

I suspect that the problem may be between the VM host and VM guest - issues with scheduling runtime for the VM or with passing network interrupts - i.e. the lumpy scenario above. I suggest benchmarking a more measurable protocol available on both the vm host and vm guest to confirm and as a basis for tuning the virtualization, however I suspect that may be difficult with vmware running on the VM host.

Comment: thank you. I would rather qualify the slowness as "lag" : every graphical change (concerning the mouse, the windows...) is slow on the laptop, but they are fast ("normal") when connecting using the host. Have you got any suggestion?